# Try Exception for pop in Python

Tags: python

t1.py  for main program

t3.py  for sub program

seems like the website have some problem
not always but sometime may meet error below in main program
is there any solution?

------error  message--------

res = list_links.pop(random.randint(1, len(list_links))) # pop of each item randomly based on the size of the list

IndexError: pop index out of range

---

t1.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Oct  5 21:51:34 2018

@author: chevady
"""
from linebot.models import *
from t3 import apple_newsss
apple_newss_content0, apple_newss_content1, apple_newss_content2 = apple_newsss()

print(apple_newss_content0)

print(apple_newss_content1)

print(apple_newss_content2)
```

t3.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import re
import os
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from flask import Flask, request, abort
#from imgurpython import ImgurClient
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def apple_newsss():

    target_url = 'http://www.appledaily.com.tw/realtimenews/section/new/'
    print('Start parsing appleNews....')
    rs = requests.session()
    res = rs.get(target_url, verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

    list_links = [] # Create empty list

    for a in soup.select("div[class='abdominis rlby clearmen']")[0].findAll(href=True): # find links based on div
            if a['href']!= None and a['href'].startswith('https://'):
                    list_links.append(a['href']) #append to the list
                    print(a['href']) #Check links

#for l in list_links: # print list to screen (2nd check)
#    print(l)


    print("\n")

    random_list = [] #create random list if needed..
    random.shuffle(list_links) #random shuffle the list
    apple_newss_content0 = ''
    apple_newss_content1 = ''
    apple_newss_content2 = ''
    for i in range(3): # specify range (5 items in this instance)
        res = list_links.pop(random.randint(1, len(list_links))) # pop of each item randomly based on the size of the list
        random_list.append(res)
    #print(res)
    #print(random_list)
    print("\n")
    apple_newss_content0=random_list[0]
    apple_newss_content1=random_list[1]
    apple_newss_content2=random_list[2]

    print(apple_newss_content0)
    print(apple_newss_content1)
    print(apple_newss_content2)

    return apple_newss_content0, apple_newss_content1, apple_newss_content2
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Your answer is in the question title?

Comment: @roganjosh  but I'm not familiar with "try except"  don't know how to make it well

Comment: Just search for it online? Wrap your code in a `try`/ `except IndexError`

Comment: @roganjosh  but I don't know the actual reason......  why the program sometimes may error but sometime OK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `len(list_links)-1`

**Ex:**

```
for i in range(3): # specify range (5 items in this instance)
    res = list_links.pop(random.randint(1, len(list_links)-1)) # pop of each item randomly based on the size of the list
    random_list.append(res)
```

Comment: Thanks!! it help!!!   but why??  it'll be great if i can get explanation for experience~~

Answer (score 1):

First point, here:

```
res = list_links.pop(random.randint(1, len(list_links)))
```

The expression `random.randint(1, len(list_links))` will return an int between 1 and `len(list_links)`, but (like most other languages FWIW) python lists indices are zero-based so you'd want `random.randint(0, len(list_links) - 1)`

Now this will not totally solve your problem, since you don't check if `list_links` has at least 3 items in it, so if it's empty or becomes empty during the for loop you'll still get an error.

*EDIT*

Also, your code is much more complicated than it needs to be. If what you want is 3 random distinct urls from `list_links`, all you need is:

```
# make sure we only have distinct urls
list_links = list(set(list_links))
# make sure the urls are in arbitrary order
random.shuffle(list_links) 
# returns the x (x <= 3) first urls 
return list_links[:3]
```

Note that this code might actually return less than three urls (it will `min(3, len(linked_lists)` urls actually, so the caller shouldn't rely on always getting 3 urls back - but that's not needed anyway: everytime you find yourself writing `somevar1, somevar2, somevarN` you really want a list (or some other sequence type) indeed. In this case, the caller code should looks like:

```
urls = apple_newsss()
for url in urls:
    print(url)
```

Comment: yes "list_links"  has absolutely more than 3  (at least 8~)
Thanks for explain~~

Comment: @ChevadyJu your current code can NOT (I repeat : "can NOT") garantee that `list_links` will contain at least 3 items. Actually it can't even garantee it contains anything.  If you trust an HTTP request to always return what you expect then you're living a wonderful  but alas totally irreal world.

Comment: s/irreal/unreal/, sorry <g>